# How to resolve "element not interactable" error in vscode extension acceptance test using WebDriverIO tests when running on Jenkins agent?

Tags: jenkins, testing, automation, vscode-extensions, webdriver-io

I am encountering an issue with my vscode extensions tests using WebDriverIO when running them on a Jenkins agent (Alma OS 9). The tests are working fine on my local setup (M1 Mac, Node 16, VSCode version 1.85), but they fail on the Jenkins agent with the following error:

```
[0-0] element not interactable in "Pull New Theme Testing.should pull new theme"
element not interactable: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.289)
    at async InputBox.clear (file:///mnt/jenkins/workspace/CI/pull-request-checks/myextension/node_modules/wdio-vscode-service/src/pageobjects/workbench/Input.ts:99:9)
```

The code snippet where it fails below particularly at the selectQuickPick:

```
const x = await inputBox.getPlaceHolder(); 
console.log(1, 'quickPicks:', x);

await wait(5000);

const quickPicks = await inputBox.getQuickPicks();
await inputBox.selectQuickPick("Item One");
```

It seems like the WebDriverIO test is unable to interact with the input box element. How can I resolve this "element not interactable" error and ensure that my tests run successfully on the Jenkins agent?